# Why is $\ \tan \theta \approx \Large{\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta}}\ $ for $\ \theta\ $ close to $\frac{\pi}{2}\ ?$

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I wanted to see what the behaviour of the steep part of the $\ \tan\ $ curve was like, i.e. the behaviour of $\ \tan(x)\ $ as $\ x\ \to \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^-.\ $ So by thinking about a shift of the graph of $\ \tan(x)\ $ by $\ \frac{\pi}{2}\ $ to the left, I put some small (positive and negative) values of $\ \theta\ $ into my calculator for the function $\ \tan\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}\right).\ $ And I think discovered the following:

> $\ \tan \theta \approx \Large{\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta}}\ $ for
> $\ \theta\ $ close to $\frac{\pi}{2}.\ $

or, in more colloquial terms,

> The steep part of $\ \tan(x)\ $ is just like the steep part of $\ \frac{1}{x}.$

But why is this the case? I couldn't deduce it easily using the [Maclaurin expansion of $\ \tan(x).\ $](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions) Is there a more intuitive explanation? I couldn't think of any explanations analogous to those explaining [small angle approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\tan \theta\equiv\cot\left(\frac {\pi}{2}-\theta\right)\equiv\frac {\cos\left(\frac {\pi}{2}-\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac {\pi}{2}-\theta\right)}$$
Can you see it now?

Answer (score 2):

So, basically you would like to see that

$$\lim_{\theta \rightarrow \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^-}\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)\tan \theta \right)= 1$$

Or, letting $t := \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\left(t\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)\right) = \lim_{t\to 0^+}\left(\frac t{\sin t}\cos t \right)=1$$
which is true.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\tan(\theta)=\cot(\frac{\pi}2-\theta)$$

And Maclaurean series for $\cot u$ where $u\to 0$ is:

$$\cot u=\frac1u-\frac u3+O(u)$$